# add/remove css class on the weightage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` container with `8 child div elements` which indicate a some color bars. Each div block contains a `weight-age` of `12.5%`.

```
<div class="progress-stacked" id="progress-div">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-fail" style="width: 10%; margin-right: 11px;"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-fail" style="width: 10%; margin-right: 11px;"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-fail" style="width: 10%; margin-right: 11px;"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-fail" style="width: 10%; margin-right: 11px;"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-fail" style="width: 10%; margin-right: 12px;"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-fail" style="width: 10%; margin-right: 12px;"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-fail" style="width: 10%; margin-right: 12px;"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-fail" style="width: 10%;"></div>
</div>
```

How would i replace the class `progress-bar-fail` with `progress-bar-success` for the value i get from API. For instance if i get 12.5, i want the first child to have `progress-bar-success` instead of `progress-bar-fail`.

If its `25`, then two child div should be replaced with `progress-bar-success` instead of `progrss-bar-fail`.

Comment: You divide the number you get from the API by 12.5, and then you have the number of elements for which you have to change the class …

Comment: Curious, because it isn't addressed in your question: What if it is 13.5? Round down to nearest? Or always round up?

Comment: @PeteScott: Can you round it to nearest... thanks Pete for your answer.

Comment: In my opinion it's better to avoid inline styles, which makes your markup unreadable and hard to work with... [Why use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS)

Comment: @Shane: Done. See my updated answer/fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this fiddle for a working test function: http://jsfiddle.net/NEWrq/5/.

I dropped the hard-coded weight-age in favor of having it figure it itself, based on the number of percentage bars that exist.

```
var testProgressUpdate = function(per)
{
    var totalBars = $(".progress-bar").length;
    var barsToModify = totalBars * (per / 100);
    barsToModify = Math.round(barsToModify);
    $(".progress-bar").removeClass().addClass("progress-bar").addClass("progress-bar-fail");
    $(".progress-bar").each(function(i)
    {
        if (i >= barsToModify) return false;        
        $(this).removeClass("progress-bar-fail").addClass("progress-bar-success");
    });
}
testProgressUpdate(50); // 4 bars
//testProgressUpdate(12.5); // 1 bar
//testProgressUpdate(13.5); // 1 bar
//testProgressUpdate(24); // 2 bars
```

Comment: Note that my code can incorrectly place multiple "progress-bar-success" classes on the elements, and the html won't reset when given a new number (success will not change to fail). I'll update the fiddle to ensure that works. (UPDATED AS NOTED)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this,

```
var value = 12.5;/*somevalue from your API*/
var targetindex = value/12.5;
targetindex = Math.floor(targetindex);
$(".progress-bar").each(function(i){
    if(i<targetindex)
        $(this).removeClass("progress-bar-fail").addClass("progress-bar-success");
});
```

Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/77Kvk/3/

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt

```
function progressUpdate(value) {
  var n = Math.floor(value / 12.5);
  $(".progress-bar:lt(" + n + ")").removeClass("progress-bar-fail").addClass("progress-bar-success");
  $(".progress-bar:gt(" + (n-1) + ")").removeClass("progress-bar-success").addClass("progress-bar-fail");
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/be6L8/2/)